# P versus NP and the Irreducibility of NP-Complete Problems to P-Complete Problems

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete

If it can be shown that a given NP-complete problem such as Clique cannot be reduced to a given P-complete problem, such as [Horn-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability), then we can conclude that P does not equal NP?

Comment: This seems rather straightforward. Am I missing some subtlety?

Comment: @MJD: Thanks for writing. No, you're not missing some subtlety. I'm just asking the question to see if I am missing one. :)